# Diagnosing a locked UI thread, form timer and Concurrency Visualizer

Tags: multithreading, timer, concurrency, signalr

I have been blessed with taking on a system, part of which is a WinForm application.  Long story short, on loading, the application seems to lock for a period of time (which varies from 10 seconds to 3 minutes or more) before proceeding normally.

By way of giving you a specific issue, there is a point where a Form timer is instantiated with an interval of 1000ms.  However the timer's Interval event doesn't seem to fire until after this 'lock' has cleared.

I know this because the code is littered with calls to a method that Debug.Prints and, also creates Concurrency visualizaton markers.

To try to resolve this issue, I installed and set up the Concurrency visualizer (2015) and created a trace.  The included image is the composited output of that trace, with the UI thread at the top; Point A is where the timer is created, B where it begins to tick (some 30 seconds late).

I know I could use a threading timer but I see this issue as a symptom of a deeper problem.

The concurrency visualizer looks great, and looks like it should really help me to nail the issue, but so far it has not shed any light on it for me.

- I would expect that given the Timer is a Form.Timer, and as such
  operates completely on the UI thread, that it would be victim of any
  processing on that thread.  The trace shows that the UI thread is
  mostly spending its time on UI (brown not green), so am I right to
  believe that had it any other work to do other than servicing the UI,
  it would slot that in happily? (my point being I guess is that to a
  noob like me the UI doesn't look blocked in that trace)
- Does the fact that we have so many threads that are in
  'Synchronization' seem unusual?
- Why does Concurrency viewer talk about "unblocking threads" (the
  thread    that unblocked this thread) instead of "blocking threads"
  (thread or resource preventing this thread executing)?
- I would have assumed I could have looked at the list of threads and
  graphically tried to see which other thread finished executing at the same
  time that the timer finally got under way (hence the rectangle on the image)    but since all threads are all blocked this doesn't seem likely.

Other possibly salient points:

App uses SignalR (its the client) to connect to a web site. during load I do get ...

> "12:30:05.6326185 - a2622cbe-57f7-476c-9f61-15b97a5d79de -
>   OnError(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Infrastructure.SlowCallbackException:
>   Possible deadlock detected. A callback registered with "HubProxy.On"
>   or "Connection.Received" has been executing for at least 10 seconds.)"

But my belief is that this method call is a victim of the issue, a symptom.

Another issue that points to threading issues is that I was also battling with code like :

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker) UpdateTaskButtonVisability);
```

Where the code within UpdateTaskButtonVisability simply didn't run, even if the method was empty.

Any enlightenment, tips, advice or pointers would be appreciated, I have been doing battle with this for days.

Many thanks

[Concurrency visualizer trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN1AX.png)

Comment: Oh, did I misunderstand then?  I assumed brown meant it was servicing the ui not that it was hammered by ui activity.  I.e i thought brown was good from a ui responsiveness perspective.  Certainly there is no human activity at this stage, except me staring at the screen with a sad face (and I doubt that's triggering ui ;) )

Comment: I just did a sample winform app that does nothing of any significance, (just a button) - and the main UI thread is solid UI, so I suspect I am right to think that brown is good, and just means the windows message stack is being catered for.  Shame cos I need a smoking gun right now!.